# Cocoa iTunes ScriptingBridge - How to play playlist shuffled / unshuffled playlist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes, scripting-bridge, accessibility-api

I see there is a property shuffle but it doesn't seem to do anything (it still plays shuffled).

I tried this but it plays shuffled. I'd like it unshuffled. Is this not possible?

```
            iTunesPlaylist *p;

            for (iTunesSource *source in [iTunes sources]) {
                if ([source kind] == iTunesESrcLibrary) {
                    p = [[source userPlaylists] objectWithName:playlist];
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (p != nil) {
                p.shuffle = NO;
                [p playOnce:NO];
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [bug](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2012/11/itunes-11-applescript-bug/) in iTunes 11 breaks the AppleScript (and hence Scripting Bridge) Shuffle command.